# user defined function to count the occurrences a randomly generated list contains an integer starting with n

Tags: python, list, function, loops

New to python and programming in general. I've written a function to generate a random list with no duplicates and numerous other callable functions that calculate something from that list(e.g. median, average, evens, odds, %n, etc.)

Problem:

1. Write a function to count the number of integers that begin with 1 and
2. Write a function to count the number of integers that end with 1

My code is

```
import random 
def fill(nx, x, y):
    lx = []
    j = 0
    while (j < nx):
        randNum = random.randint(x, y)
        if randNum not in lx:
            lx.append(randNum)
            j = j + 1
    return lx


def digit1x(lx):
#some kind of count
    cnt_1x = 0
#loop to iterate lx?
    for i in lx: # not sure what to really do from here
        if i == 
    return 0


 def digitx1(lx):
     # same problem 
 return 0

 def sum(lx):
     s=0
     for i in lx:
     s+=i
 return s
```

## Calling the Functions

```
n = 25 
a = 10 
b = 60 
myList = fill(n, a, b) 
print(myList)
```

## Output

```
[32, 27, 57, 17, 14, 55, 29, 42, 23, 12, 11, 47, 60, 41, 31, 20, 
21, 26, 56, 35, 30, 44, 54, 10, 50]

Sum ==   844 
Minimum  10 
Maximum ==  60 
Average ==  33.76
```

## Expected

```
x = digit1x(myList) 
print("10 the number of integers that start with the digit 1 == ", x) 


output: "...==" 5  



y = digitx1(myList)
 print("11 the number of integers that end with the digit 1 == ", y)


output:"...==" 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def digit1x(lx):
    return len([i for i in lx if str(i)[0]=='1'])

def digitx1(lx):
    return len([i for i in lx if str(i)[-1]=='1'])
```

and if you are short on memory and processing resources:

```
def digit1x(lx):
    return sum(1 for i in lx if i%10==1])

def digitx1(lx):
    return sum(1 for i in lx if i/(10**int(math.log(i,10)))==1)
```

In this case, you are avoiding the string conversion and use only some fast calculations. You also are using a generator for the sum, and hence no extra list is created.

Comment: Yes! thank you so much. I tried converting to a string but never used the index correctly

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
def count1(lx):
    return len([i for i in lx if i%10==1])
```

Comment: Thank you! a %n that would work for ints ending in 1?

Comment: eguaio answer for this is shorter one. that should do the job.